# Upgraded to 12.04 before updating 11.10

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, package-management

I believe I'm the only person that did that. I've read that I must update my 11.10 before upgrading. Then the next morning I just opened the update-manager and upgraded to 12.04.  I forgot all about that I have to update.

Anyway now I'm getting some errors, is there anyway to fix the problem and install the missing dependencies or I just have to make a clean 12.04 install and lose all the time that it took me to tweak my Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried booting into the recovery mode option from Grub startup menu??
Have you done a file system check using fsck?? Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

There are some fixes. A clean install may be a quick and dirty way out but that's probably what I would do. The tweaks you have done may well be what is causing the problems. Usually, problems are caused by old non-standard configuration files in your system. Try opening a new clean user account. If this show no problems, your config settings are the problem. If you want to try cleaning things up, you can try some of these - but backup everything first:

```
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^
```

not forgetting the caret.